# Creating a new Dataframe based on rows with certain values and removing the rows from the original Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to separate a Dataframe based on rows with a certain value in multiple columns, so that the original Dataframe is split in two with all rows containing the value in one Dataframe and the other Dataframe with the residual rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df
    A   B   C   D
0   51  86  15  80
1   61  53  75  66
2   80  48  23  58
3   86  25  37  99
4   50  11  87  71
... ... ... ... ...
95  34  40  43  40
96  89  16  83  72
97  97  32  24  26
98  27  83  75  29
99  24  50  40  43
100 rows × 4 columns

df[~df.isin([-1])].dropna()
    A   B   C   D
0   51  86  15  80.0
1   61  53  75  66.0
2   80  48  23  58.0
3   86  25  37  99.0
4   50  11  87  71.0
... ... ... ... ...
95  34  40  43  40.0
96  89  16  83  72.0
97  97  32  24  26.0
98  27  83  75  29.0
99  24  50  40  43.0
98 rows × 4 columns

df[df.isin([-1])].dropna()
A   B   C   D
```

is what i tried so far and the first part worked correctly. However `df[df.isin([-1])].dropna()` failed.

Comment: Thtat is probably because the original df contains no value which has -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Use `any(axis=1)` to keep only one boolean value for each row instead of using `dropna(how='all')`

The same with a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2022)
vals = np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], size=(10, 4), p=[.2, .4, .4])
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=list('ABCD'))

m = df.isin([-1]).any(axis=1)  # or df.eq(-1).any(axis=1)
df1, df2 = df[m], df[~m]
```

Output:

```
>>> df.assign(M=m)
   A  B  C  D      M
0 -1  0 -1 -1   True
1  1  0  1  1  False
2  1  1  1  1  False
3  1  1  0  0  False
4  0  1  1 -1   True
5  1  0  0  1  False
6 -1  0  1  0   True
7  0  0  0  0  False
8  1 -1  1  0   True
9  1  1  0  1  False

>>> df1
   A  B  C  D
0 -1  0 -1 -1
4  0  1  1 -1
6 -1  0  1  0
8  1 -1  1  0

>>> df2
   A  B  C  D
1  1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  0  0
5  1  0  0  1
7  0  0  0  0
9  1  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets assume you would like to filter data by value equals to `80`.

Possible solution is the following:

```
# pip install pandas

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df
```

[image]

```
# df1 = df[~df.isin([80])].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
# or
df1 = df[~df.eq(80).any(1)].reset_index(drop=True)
df1
```

[image]

```
df2 = df[df.eq(80).any(1)].reset_index(drop=True)
df2
```

[image]